# Gibt es einen Grund, warum das Antwortwort zu „wie“, nämlich „so“, nicht mit D beginnt?

Tags: adverb, morphology, interrogative, conjunction

Im Deutschen ist für die meisten Fragewörter die Struktur:

- warum – darum
- was – das
- wo – da

Warum ist das für *wie* und *so* anders?

(*Welche* und *solche* ist dann vermutlich davon abgeleitet.)

Ich habe eine ähnliche Frage auf ELU gestellt:
https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29966/why-does-how-not-follow-the-structure-of-the-other-interrogatives

Comment: @deceze: Hast du einen Tab oder Leerzeichen ans Zeilenende gesetzt?

Comment: Zwei Leerzeichen. http://german.stackexchange.com/editing-help#linebreaks

Comment: Vielleicht hat es ja was damit zu tun, dass im Englischen das Wort für „wie“, *how*, das einzige Fragewort ist, was nicht mit *wh* beginnt?

Comment: Zumindest beim Fragewort "wo" ist regional auch "do" zulässig. Es ist die Dialektform von "da". Es taucht in mehreren deutschen Dialekten auf, z.B. im Hessischen oder Saarländischen. Mir fallen noch mehr Fragewörter ein, bei denen es die von Dir genannte Struktur gibt:

- Wessen - dessen
- Wann - dann
- Woher - daher
- Worin - darin
- Wem - dem
- Wozu - dazu

usw.

Comment: @Phira: Du solltest vielleicht einen Indogermanistin oder ein etymologisches Wörterbuch konsultieren.

Answer (score 2):

Man könnte argumentieren, dass das überkorrekte Frage-Antwort-Spiel lauten müsste:

- wie – auf diese Weise, derart, dergestalt

Und "so" wäre nur die "schlampige" Kurzform. Dann würde man das *D* wiederfinden.

Aber die tatsächlich naheliegenste Antwort ist natürlich: "so".